# How to improve pg_basebackup speed

Tags: postgresql

How to improve pg_basebackup speed. I can not find the parallelism option for pg_basebackup. There is no any parallelism option for pg_basebackup? Thank you. I just want to create slave database fast. The database is 5TB and it takes more time for creating Slave database. If there is no any parallel option how can I avoid this time problem?

Command for creating Slave

pg_basebackup  -Xs -h 172.31.34.215 -U repuser --checkpoint=fast -D  /var/lib/postgresql/14/ter -R --slot=replication_slot -C

Comment: There is no explicit parallel option to `pg_basebackup`. What is the actual complete  command you are running? Add as update to your question.

Comment: Added to main question

Comment: You still have not shown what the exact command is that you are using?

Comment: I am sorry. Added